# Remove punctuation between urlseen and url, using biblatex (American Sociological Association reference formatting)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, chicago-style

I've just about gotten my bibliography up to my advisor's standards, but there's one thing that I just can't seem to figure out.

I need to remove the punctuation between the printouts of {urlseen} and {url} in my bibliography output.

For example, this:

> Author. 2013. “Web Page Title: Web Page Subtitle.” Organization. Retrieved December 15, 2014. (http://web.page.com/).

Should change to this:

> Author. 2013. “Web Page Title: Web Page Subtitle.” Organization. Retrieved December 15, 2014 (http://web.page.com/).

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,abbreviate=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{./minimal.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{ %
    \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibparens{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{pages}{pp. {#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {Retrieved},
}

\begin{document}
\uspunctuation

\cite{Aut13}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my minimal bibliography:

```
@online{Aut13,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Web Page Title},
    date = {2013},
    url = {http://web.page.com/},
    subtitle = {Web Page Subtitle},
    organization = {Organization},
    urldate = {2014-12-15}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to patch the bibliography driver `online` provided by `biblatex-chicago` to achieve what you want.

So, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
 {\newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
  {\iffieldundef{doi}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{url}}}%
  {\printfield{doi}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{eprint}%
  \newunit\newblock
 }
 {\setunit{\addspace}
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
  {\iffieldundef{doi}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{url}}}%
  {\printfield{doi}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{eprint}%
  \setunit{\addspace}
 }
 {}
 {}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{minimal.bib}
@online{Aut13,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Web Page Title},
    date = {2013},
    url = {http://web.page.com/},
    subtitle = {Web Page Subtitle},
    organization = {Organization},
    urldate = {2014-12-15}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,abbreviate=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{./minimal.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{ %
    \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibparens{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{pages}{pp. {#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {Retrieved},
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
 {\newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
  {\iffieldundef{doi}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{url}}}%
  {\printfield{doi}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{eprint}%
  \newunit\newblock
 }
 {\setunit{\addspace}
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
  {\iffieldundef{doi}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{url}}}%
  {\printfield{doi}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{eprint}%
  \setunit{\addspace}
 }
 {}
 {}

\begin{document}
\uspunctuation

\cite{Aut13}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great, that works perfectly!  If anyone (or a search engine) wonders, this is a necessary part of American Sociological Association reference formatting, per the fourth edition of the style guide.

Comment: @JoeRemenak Glad it helped!

Comment: @JoeRemenak I've changed the title hoping a search engine is able to find this thread :-)